# How to access a value from an object where the type might not be there

Tags: typescript, redux

So I'm relatively new to using Typescript regularly and am trying to figure out how to do something that is easy in Javascript.

```
const handlerMap = {
  [actionTypes.updateVersion]: handleVersionUpdate,
};

export default function appReducer(
  state: IAppState,
  action: IAction,
): IAppState {
  const handler = handlerMap[action.type];

  if (!handler) {
    return state;
  }

  return handler(state, action);
}
```

So this is a redux reducer (I know it's an atypical format) and I simply want to use the defined handler if it exists, and if it's undefined return the original state.  But I'm getting a typescript compile error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"app/update_version" | "auth/signIn" | "auth/signIn/loading" | "auth/signIn/success"' can't be used to index type '{ "app/update_version": (state: IAppState, action: IUpdateVersion) => IAppState; }'.
  Property 'auth/signIn' does not exist on type '{ "app/update_version": (state: IAppState, action: IUpdateVersion) => IAppState; }'.
```

So I understand what it's saying, that `action.type` could be something that no key exists for on the handlerMap. But that's my intention, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Include the code of `IAction` and `IAppState` interfaces

Answer (score 0):

There are four possible string values of `action.type` (from your error message), but only one possible key of `handlerMap`.  This is not a problem for you because you are acknowledging and handling the possibility that `action.type` is not a valid key of `handlerMap`.

The simplest way to handle this is to assert correctness using `as`.  We say that `action.type` is the correct type to be used as a key of `handlerMap`.

```
const handler = handlerMap[action.type as keyof typeof handlerMap];
```

---

The more complicated way would be to broaden the type of `handlerMap` instead of letting TypeScript infer a more specific type.  It becomes complicated to correctly type the value here and to maintain the relationship between the keys and the values (so that `handleVersionUpdate` knows that it always receives a version update action).  If that relationship is not important than this should work:

```
const handlerMap: { [K in IAction['type']]?: (state: IAppState, action: IAction) => IAppState } = {
  [actionTypes.updateVersion]: handleVersionUpdate,
};
```

But save yourself the headache and just use the `as` assertion.